# Comparing two GTX 1070s for Mining

Tags: graphics-cards

I am planning on getting into the Cryptocurrency scene pretty soon, and I plan to mine non-SHA256 coins (i.e coins not like Bitcoin), and therefore I plan to use GPUs extensively, rather than ASIC hardware.

I have a fairly tight budget right now per card, around $450 USD, and AFAIK the GTX 10 Series are the best bang-for-buck for non-Bitcoin coins. I have found these two cards on Amazon (links below)

Card 1 --> [EVGA](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01KVZBNY0)

Card 2 --> [Gigabyte](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B075DF4PTF)

What I want to know is, which of these cards is better for mining with? Even if it's just a marginal advantage over the other. I want to get the most performance from these cards before I have to replace them later down the line.

I have done research about this question, but have not found any concrete evidence that can help me decide the victor.

Thanks for viewing!

Comment: just to make sure, have you actually calculated how much the electricity will cost you compared to the money you make?

Comment: I have. I am looking at a 547% percentage profit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're both GTX 1070 graphics cards with 8 GB of GDDR5 running at 8.008 GT/s on a 256-bit bus.  They both use two cooling fans with similar heatsink setups, require one 8-pin PCIe power connection, and have the same five output connectors.  In short, they're virtually identical cards for an identical price of $439.99.

If you're looking for a reason to pick one over the other, the EVGA card is clocked 0.7% faster than the Gigabyte.  It's also half an inch shorter and three-quarters of an inch narrower, making for a better fit in a crowded case.  The true power draw isn't specified, but the faster clock speed probably corresponds to an increase of 1.5%.